# Mapping based on found value

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to map but skip some elements based on found elements. The essence of the issue is here.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

i = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] % 2 == 0:
       a[i] *= 2
    else:
       i += 1
    i += 1
```

I can express this with explicit recursion in Haskell by passing along an index variable and an accumulator.

```
f :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
f index list acc = if index < length list then 
                   if even (list !! index) then f (index + 1) list (acc ++ [(list !! index) * 2]) else f (index + 2) list (acc ++ [list !! index, list !! (index + 1)])
                   else acc

f 0 [1,2,3,4,5] []
```

But this feels really ugly, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I looked those functions up but I don't see how using them together would solve my problem, do you have an example?

Comment: Blah, misread the question. Those definitely aren't gonna work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `mapAccumL` and use a boolean accumulator to represent whether the previous number was odd?

```
f = snd . mapAccumL go False
  where
    go False n | even n = (False, n * 2)
    go True n | even n = (False, n)
    go _ n = (True, n)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I haven't got it wrong,

> I think the code is going to multiply the number if it is even then
> move to the next one otherwise move forward twice

and I've try something like this

```
In [6]: walk :: [Int] -> [Int] 
      : walk [] = [] 
      : walk [x] = if even x then [x*2] else [x] 
      : walk (x:y:xs) = if even x then (2*x): walk (y:xs) else [x,y] ++ walk xs 
      :        
        
In [7]: walk [1..5] 
      :                                                                         
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and it yields the same result.

Comment: This does solve the problem, at least the one I have as an exmaple, but it still uses explicit recursion. I was hoping for some clever map + fold thing that I could use. My real world problem also needs to jump ahead sometimes by 23 elements, so something like `(x:y:xs)` doesn't really work

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Explicit recursion can be easier to read than rarely used special folds like `mapAccumL`. Moreover, your code uses `length` and `!!` at each recursive call, which is inefficient, while this answer avoids that. If you need to jump 23 elements, one can recurse as `walk (drop 23 xs)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a fold, where you leave a value unmodified if the previous value was odd. It ought to be a left fold, since you’re proceeding from left to right, so this can use the common pattern of accumulating a list from the left and then reversing it at the end.

```
f = reverse . fst . foldl' go ([], False)
  where
    go (xs, skip) x
      | skip = (x : xs, False)
      | x `mod` 2 == 0 = (x * 2 : xs, False)
      | otherwise = (x : xs, True)
```

This is essentially using `Bool` as a counter for the number of elements to skip, whose value can only be 0 or 1. If you needed to skip more elements in some circumstances, you could use an integer rather than a Boolean.

I arrived at this solution by restructuring the loop from the original code:

```
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] % 2 == 0:
       a[i] *= 2
    else:
       i += 1
    i += 1
```

Into one that decouples the state (whether to skip an element) from the list index:

```
i = 0
skip = False
while i < len(a):
    if a[i] % 2 == 0:
        if not skip:
            a[i] *= 2
        skip = False
    else:
        skip = True
    i += 1
```

You can also do this without explicit recursion *or* a fold, by decoupling the even/odd test from the iteration, and zipping them together:

```
f = zipWith3 go xs evens afterOdds
  where
    go x isEven afterOdd
      | isEven, not afterOdd = x * 2
      | otherwise            = x

    -- Whether each element is even.
    evens = map even xs

    -- Whether the previous element was odd.
    -- Note the initial ‘False’ prepended.
    afterOdds = False : map not evens
```

For example, given an input like `[2, 4, 1, 6]`, `evens` is `[True, True, False, True]` and `afterOdds` is `[False, False, False, True, False]`, so `go` is called as:

- `go 2 True False` = `4`
- `go 4 True False` = `8`
- `go 1 False False` = `1`
- `go 6 True True` = `6`

Giving `[4, 8, 1, 6]`. The extra `False` in `afterOdds` is ignored since the other lists run out of elements by that point in the zipping.

This can even be written using exclusively list comprehensions with `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}` enabled:

```
f xs =
  [ if isEven && not afterOdd then x * 2 else x
  | x <- xs
  | isEven <- [even x | x <- xs]
  | afterOdd <- False : [odd x | x <- xs]
  ]
```

To skip multiple elements this way, you could again use an integer instead of a Boolean, indicating the number of elements *since* an odd element, for example with `scanl'`:

```
sinceLastOdd = scanl' go Nothing
  where
    go n x
      | odd x     = Just 0
      | otherwise = fmap succ n
```

```
> sinceLastOdd [2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 3, 10, 12]
[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Just 0,Just 1,Just 2,Just 0,Just 1,Just 2]
```